# Unsqueeze the fraction

Tags: math-mode, equations, fractions

For the LaTeX code below,

```
 \begin{equation}
Fitness(\CS)=
\begin{cases}
    0.5 + 0.5 \cdot G(\CS)                        & if\ V(\CS)=0 \\
    0.5\cdot G(\CS)-\frac{V(\CS)}{V_{Tot}(\CS)}   & otherwise.
\end{cases}~\label{eq:fitness}
\end{equation}
```

I get the output

[image]

It looks like the fraction `\frac{V(\CS)}{V_{Tot}(\CS)}` is a bit squeezed here,I would prefer

[image]

which looks less squeezed. How could I do that?

Comment: @Werner The `dcases` environment is defined by `mathtools`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) defined `dcases` which puts the entries inside in display math mode. This causes fractions and other mode-varying elements to conform to their largest size:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% mathtools also loads amsmath (http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\newcommand{\CS}{CS}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Fitness}{Fitness}
\begin{document}

% Original cases
\begin{equation}
  Fitness(\CS)=
  \begin{cases}
    0.5 + 0.5 \cdot G(\CS)                        & if\ V(\CS)=0 \\
    0.5\cdot G(\CS)-\frac{V(\CS)}{V_{Tot}(\CS)}   & otherwise.
  \end{cases}\label{eq:fitness1}
\end{equation}

% Updated dcases, operator definition and text
\begin{equation}
  \Fitness(\CS)=
  \begin{dcases}
    0.5 + 0.5 \cdot G(\CS)                        & \text{if\ }V(\CS)=0 \\
    0.5\cdot G(\CS)-\frac{V(\CS)}{V_{\text{Tot}}(\CS)}   & \text{otherwise.}
  \end{dcases}\label{eq:fitness2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Textual elements are forced as text using `\text`, while an operator like `Fitness` should also be declared as such. See the [`amsmath` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) for more on these topics.